# Should I send an email to my manager regarding low employee morale?

Tags: professionalism, morale

I've been working at company XYZ as a web developer in New York for a few years now. The company has steadily declined and I feel obligated to say something to my manager, the owner of XYZ.

XYZ is a small digital marketing startup, with about 10 employees. My colleagues and I have discussed how we feel working for XYZ and we all agree it's not a fun environment.

I've written up a brief email explaining why morale is low in the company and I'm unsure of how good of an idea it is to send it.

Does the email below come off as professional and is it a good idea to send?

[image]

Comment: It would be far better to do it face-to-face.

Comment: You probably should check with your coworkers before speaking on their behalf - you might all agree it's not fun, but that's not same as agreeing to take it to management

Comment: If you're going to email him, please correct "it's fun" to "its fun."

Comment: Also, if you don't have paper and trash bags, I think you're past issues of "fun."

Comment: Trash bags were the most fun part @MissMonicaE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would rather ask him out for lunch or something, and talk to him face to face instead of sending him such a letter. Sending such a letter sounds more like you are whining, rather than voicing areas of improvement for the company.

Also I wouldn't consider talking to a manger whose company does not even provide very basic equipment such as paper and garbage bags. Instead I would walk away and never look back!

Comment: Bonus point for walking away... this kind of story rarely ends well.

Answer (score 7):

Although you may feel you're getting your point across more clearly via a letter, an initial one on one conversation would be the best place to start.

That will better open up the issue to a more thorough discussion.

If your demeanor is smooth like your letter is conveying, I would think your manager would at least be receptive to your ideas and issues.

It's not a time to be threatening, that's for sure (it doesn't seem like you would be). But depending on how things turn out you may eventually have to call it a day and explore other opportunities.

Answer (score 4):

Discussing something like this with your boss is a sensitive conversation.  A letter can work as well as a face to face talk, but I would suggest they both follow the same structure.

1. Talk about the things that people enjoy about the company and things that historically were highlights.
2. Mention the things that are causing low morale, and give specific examples.  "The garbage is really becoming a issue, we dont even have new bags to change out" rather then "The office always stinks".  "I am personally having issues getting my tasks done because I have 3 managers who seem to be working at cross purposes with my priorities" rather than "My deadlines are unreasonable"
3. List out things that can be done to increase the morale of your coworkers.  "It is really helpful when we have a stock of utensils in the kitchen.  The employees appreciate it, and it seems to promote people bringing in lunch from home and spending lunch time hanging out together"

Stay positive and stay concrete and realistic.  Dont tell your boss that your coworkers expect Ice cream party Friday every week.  But if the company used to do that, suggest it as a occasional treat.

Answer (score 3):

As people said before talking to your manager would be the best idea but if you still want to send this e-mail it would probably be a more secure idea to print it and have the whole office sign it. Then it wouldn't only be your head rolling and it might get the boss to think about how improve things.

But be realy carefull about it , it can also be seen as a global whining and your boss could get quite upset about it which would lead you all to even worse conditions.